# tt_news default news image based on category image

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tt-news

I'm using the extension tt_news at my TYPO3 installation to publish news. Now I would like to have a default picture for a news, if no picture is set. This default picture should depend on the category selected and the category image should be used.

At the moment, I only a have a default picture for every news. I realised it with the following TS:

```
displayLatest.image.noImage_stdWrap {
cObject = IMAGE
cObject {
    file = fileadmin/default-pic.jpg
    wrap =
    } 
}
```

How can I adopt this to use the category image?

Answer (score -1):

You could use the other news extension "news". It has a FLUID template. You can program the code inside the html code so to show a default picture according the category value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to use the extension "news", but migrating is not possible at the moment. Therefore I'm looking for a solution for "tt_news".